# Create database table in kohana 3.2

Tags: database, kohana-3, create-table

How to create table using ORM or Database builder with kohana 3.2? Is this possible at all?
I saved the table definition (create sql) in a file. I'm sure the sql works because I used it in phpMyAdmin and it works. How can I execute the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Database::instance()->query(NULL, 'raw query here');
```

Kohana's ORM does not have the capability to create tables for you. You can define the columns manually, but if I recall correctly not with enough information necessary to recreate the table.

I've seen two ORM's made for Kohana that could create tables. They were Sprig and Jelly if I remember correctly, I don't think they are maintained anymore though.

Comment: Jelly is still maintained somewhere, but for a more full featured ORM for Kohana that is still actively developed (i.e. "not abandoned", not "unstable") check out https://github.com/OpenBuildings/jam